# Show $e^z e^w = e^{z+w} \ \forall \ z,w \in \mathbb C$ by differentiation of $f(t):=e^{w+tz}e^{-tz}, \ t \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Show $e^z e^w = e^{z+w} \ \forall \ z,w \in \mathbb C$ by differentiation of $f(t):=e^{w+tz}e^{-tz}, \ t \in \mathbb R$.

I have already showed $e^z e^{-z} = 1$ for $z \in \mathbb C$.

This result should be extended to the above result and a hint is given on using differentiation of the given function $f$.

However calculating $f^{'}(x)=ze^{w+tz}e^{-tz} + e^{w+tz}(-z)e^{-tz} = 0$ ?

So the derrivative is $0$ (assuming my computations are right), what can I conclude from this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f$ is $0$ then $f$ is a constant:

$$f(t)=f(0)=e^w$$
hence we have for all $t\in\Bbb R$
$$e^{w+tz}e^{-tz}=e^w\iff e^{w+tz}=e^{tz}e^w$$
and let $v=tz$ we find the desired result
$$e^{w+v}=e^we^v$$

Answer (score 0):

That $f$ is constant. Especially, $f(1)=f(0)$.

Comment: Yes I figured that out myself. But then $f(0) = e^w$, so $f(t) = e^w$ ? How does this tell me $e^z e^w = e^{z+w}$ ?

I have $e^{w+z} e^{-z} = e^{w}$, so $e^{w+z} = e^{w}e^{z}$ !

Thank you.